# ViewStack Container Vs Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

What is the main difference Between ViewStack Container and Canvas?

thanks,
ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewStack is essentially a stack of other containers that you can switch between.  While Canvas is a single container.  ViewStack also supports deferred instantiation which speeds up performance.